# How to add campus selection status in LinkedIn?

Tags: linkedin

I've recently been selected for an IT company in our campus recruitment. Can I add this to my LinkedIn profile?

I'm in my final year. There isn't such an option as far as I observed. Is there any way you know to add it? Is it even recommended to add such event to our profile with out yet starting to work in the company?

I've been trying to add at work position in profile editing section. I'm required to add start date and end date of job. But, since, I'm going to join in August, I've added August as start month. But, LinkedIn doesn't accept it since I need to add a position I've already started working at. So, is there any other way/section where I can add my current employment status like "got selected for X company"?

Here is the scenario:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> So, is there any other way/section where I can add my current employment status like "got selected for X company"?

No, there isn't.